# Antlr4 - Ordering of clauses

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have this rule:

```
query
    : SELECT  selectAttribute (',' selectAttribute)*
      FROM from
      (WHERE where=booleanExpression)?
      (ORDER BY sortItem (',' sortItem)*)?
      (LIMIT limit=(INTEGER_VALUE | ALL))?
      (IGNOREHIDDENFILES ignoreHiddenFiles=booleanValue)?
      (FOLLOWSYMLINKS followSymlinks=booleanValue)?
      SEMICOLON
    ;
```

This is valid;

```
SELECT name FROM /tmp 
IGNOREHIDDENFILES true
FOLLOWSYMLINKS true
```

However, this is not valid:

```
SELECT name FROM /tmp 
FOLLOWSYMLINKS true
IGNOREHIDDENFILES true
```

I want to tell the rule that the order doesn't matter for `IGNOREHIDDENFILES` and `FOLLOWSYMLINKS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the top of my head - create a subrule, and use it with * in `query`.

***EDIT*** After @NiloPaim pointed out in the comment, I've made the change not to use the * wildcard.Something like:

```
query: query_first SEMICOLON
     | query_first ignoreHiddenFilesPart (followSymlinksPArt)? SEMICOLON
     | query_first followSymlinksPArt (ignoreHiddenFilesPart)? SEMICOLON
     ;
query_first : SELECT  selectAttribute (',' selectAttribute)*
      FROM from
      (WHERE where=booleanExpression)?
      (ORDER BY sortItem (',' sortItem)*)?
      (LIMIT limit=(INTEGER_VALUE | ALL))?
            ;
ignoreHiddenFilesPart: IGNOREHIDDENFILES ignoreHiddenFiles=booleanValue ;
followSymlinksPArt: FOLLOWSYMLINKS followSymlinks=booleanValue ;
```

Comment: Just be careful with one thing: you can have repeated IGNOREHIDDENFILES or FOLLOWSYMLINKS clauses on your input with no parsing errors. Maybe you will want check this on a listener or a visitor...

Comment: @NiloPaim +1 exactly

Comment: @Flukey I've edited the answer after it was accepted, but taken into account NiloPaim's insight , I hope that's fine :)